# How can I make the Rust compiler generate AVX2 instructions?

Tags: optimization, rust, avx, avx2

I'm trying to write a simple routine to make use of AVX2 instructions.

As an example, given the following two versions of the same function:

```
fn mul1(xs: &[i32], ys: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    // Assuming xs.len() == ys.len()
    xs.iter().zip(ys.iter()).map(|(x, y)| x * y).collect()
}

fn mul2(xs: &[i32], ys: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 8;
    // Assuming xs.len() == ys.len() and xs.len() % CHUNK_SIZE == 0
    let chunks = xs.chunks_exact(CHUNK_SIZE).zip(ys.chunks_exact(CHUNK_SIZE));
    let result_chunks = chunks.map(|(c1, c2)| c1.into_iter().zip(c2.into_iter()).map(|(x, y)| x * y));
    result_chunks.flatten().collect()
}
```

And the associated [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Ko81nhnT1), I'm not really seeing wide multiplications being done in the second one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mul1` is vectorized around jump label `LBB3_9`. The second isn't vectorized. It does some scalar looping around `LBB4_9` and `LBB4_6`. Seems like `mul2` does not figure out how to preallocate the whole vector and that prevents vectorization

Comment: Might be unrelated but you should really [take slices (`&[i32]`) instead of references to vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function).

Comment: Makes sense. I've made the suggested changes. `mul2` is still not generating any `vpmulld` instruction

Comment: As pointed out by @Homer512, `mul1` produces vectorized instructions. That said, more complex problems might fit better with the second approach and I can't quite understand why it's not working

Comment: `flatten()` is bad for optimization. It cannot give an accurate `size_hint()`, and therefore needs a condition to grow. This might be the reason.

Comment: However, the compiler vectorizes the first version well, so why would you bother?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason boils down to `flatten()`.

The first version can always give an accurate and precise estimation of how items it'll yield (the smaller of `xs`'s and `ys`'s lengths). In technical terms, it impls [`TrustedLen`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.TrustedLen.html). Specialization in `collect()` detects that, and allocates all space ahead of time, without needing to check for each item if the collection needs to grow. Therefore, LLVM can vectorize the function, because there aren't grow checks.

`flatten()`, however, cannot be `TrustedLen`, because each item may be of a different size. Technically, it could in this case, because `chunks_exact()` yields equal chunks, but it isn't implemented. So `collect()` needs to insert checks for growth, and therefore LLVM cannot vectorize this function.

Comment: A compiler could in theory still optimistically vectorize, assuming that reallocations are infrequent.  But that's harder.  And the mainstream C compiler back-ends other than classic ICC are completely incapable of auto-vectorizing when the loop trip-count isn't calculable ahead of the first iteration, so transforming to an inner loop like `while(pos<endpos && !reallocation_needed){...}` wouldn't help LLVM.  ([Auto vectorization with Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73118583))